# Is there an assymetrical diff option or command on GNU/linux?

Tags: bash, shell

is there a version of diff that runs

```
diff a.txt b.txt
```

and shows only lines in a.txt that are not in b.txt or lines in a.txt that are modified versions of lines in b.txt.

(I am running GNU/linux mint, but I presume this to be of little relevance)

Comment: Do you need to be able to distinguish between *addition* of lines to one file relative to the other on one hand, and *modification* of corresponding lines on the other?

Comment: Nope.

Any line, new or modified, on one, and no lines from the other

Comment: Sounds like you may actually want `comm` and not `diff` at all. It's much, **much** faster and more memory-efficient, too -- doubly so if your input files are pre-sorted, in which case it becomes O(n+m) time and O(1) memory (`comm` requires sorted input, so if your inputs aren't sorted, you end up with `comm -23 <(sort </tmp/a) <(sort </tmp/b)` -- which still has better worst-case performance than `diff`). See [BashFAQ #36: *How can I get all lines that are: in both of two files (set intersection) or in only one of two files (set subtraction)?*](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/036)

Comment: I thought of `comm`, too, @CharlesDuffy, but at first I supposed that the lines must be context sensitive, such that sorting the files as required by `comm` is not viable.  That supposition was based entirely on the OP's choice of `diff`, however, and I agree that if `comm` would in fact serve the purpose then it is a better choice.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, comm requires sorted files. This is not useful for me, but might be to others, so perhaps you should post it as an answer?

@CharlesDuffy

Comment: @josinalvo it requires sorted streams; those streams can be made from unsorted files -- that's slow, but not as slow as worst-case diff behavior. The real question is whether sorting the output destroys some of its meaning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.

```
diff --changed-group-format='%>' --unchanged-group-format='' /tmp/a /tmp/b
```

Answer (score 1):

If the lines of content are independent such that changing their sort order doesn't change their meaning, you may wish to use `comm` rather than `diff`: `diff` does extra, [memory-intensive](https://superuser.com/questions/1476026/why-is-gnu-diff-such-a-memory-hog) work to try to build the shortest possible changeset (with a fairly complex algorithm), whereas `comm` simply compares a line at a time between two inputs (an algorithm that is possible only when those inputs are sorted).

If your inputs are both pre-sorted, this can look like:

```
# Extremely fast and memory-efficient
comm -23 a.txt b.txt
```

...otherwise, sorting them in real-time:

```
# Still faster than diff's worst-case, and supports processing content
# larger-than-memory, which diff doesn't.
comm -23 <(sort <a.txt) <(sort b.txt)
```

(`sort` *does* need working space correlated with the size of its inputs, but unlike diff, it's able to shuffle that content out of RAM into temporary files and combine those files via a merge sort when insufficient RAM is available).